# Where are local runner files stored?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I use gitlab.com with my own runners (they are executed on my server).

When a `script` entry in `.gitlab-ci.yml` is executed in a shell context, where are files created? As an example, for the example below running on a shell runner

```
script:
  - date > hello.txt
```

where should I look for `hello.txt`?

The specific reason for this question is for cleanup purposes: I would like to remove old directories my runners create and populate with temporary data.

Comment: Check `~gitlab-runner/builds` directory. There should be a copy of your repo and in this copy look for the location of `.gitlab-ci.yml`.

Comment: @DmitriChubarov: thank you. This is interesting because I see 3 subfolders there, 2 of which the names correspond to the gitlab-assigned names of my two runners. There is a third directory that was used today, with code I updated today. I wonder where it came from (there is only my code inside, this is not a hack or something like that). If you would not mind turning your comment into an answer I would gladly accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quite a few options here, so I'll just add, *it depends*.

If you have a standard Linux shell runner, without any extra configuration and installed the way GitLab suggest, you'll have a path something along the lines of:

```
/home/gitlab-runner/builds/$RUNNER_TOKEN_KEY/$CONCURRENT_ID/$NAMESPACE/$PROJECT_NAME
```

This directory can be changed with [builds_dir](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runners-section) option in the runner `config.toml`.

---

Another point to add, is that in your script, you can also echo out the location files, and also to specify where to save a file on the runner, eg:

```
script:
  - echo ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}
  - date > ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/hello.txt
```

See [GitLab's pre-defined environment variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#predefined-environment-variables) for more options.

---

By default, all jobs are within this `${CI_PROJECT_DIR}`, so when you start a `script` section, you can usually safely assume that you are in this directory without having to do a `cd ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}` for example.

You also most likely want all the job to be done within this `${CI_PROJECT_DIR}` because the GitLab runner also handles the cleanup when a new job starts. By default, the runner does a `git clean -ffdx` after checking out the repository, and so in this example, would remove the `hello.txt` file before continuing with the job. See [git clean flags](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/README.html#git-clean-flags) for more information.

Just be wary of [handling concurrency](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/README.html#handling-concurrency) on shell runners if they share the same build directory.

HTH!

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I found the files. To verbatim copy a previous comment: This is interesting because I see 3 subfolders there, 2 of which the names correspond to the gitlab-assigned names of my two runners. There is a third directory that was used today, with code I updated today. I wonder where it came from (there is only my code inside, this is not a hack or something like that).